# Replicating elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replicate

I have a numpy array say

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])
```

I have an array 'replication' of the same size where replication[i,j](>=0) denotes how many times a[i][j] should be repeated along the row. Obiviously, replication array follows the invariant that np.sum(replication[i]) have the same value for all i.
For example, if

```
replication = array([[1, 2, 1],
                     [1, 1, 2],
                     [2, 1, 1]])
```

then the final array after replicating is:

```
new_a = array([[1, 2, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6, 6],
           [7, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Presently, I am doing this to create new_a:

```
 ##allocate new_a
 h = a.shape[0]
 w = a.shape[1]
 for row in range(h):
      ll = [[a[row][j]]*replicate[row][j] for j in range(w)]
      new_a[row] = np.array([item for sublist in ll for item in sublist])
```

However, this seems to be too slow as it involves using lists. Can I do the intended entirely in numpy, without the use of python lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten out your `replication` array, then use the [`.repeat()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.repeat.html) method of `a`:

```
import numpy as np

a = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]])

replication = array([[1, 2, 1],
                     [1, 1, 2],
                     [2, 1, 1]])

new_a = a.repeat(replication.ravel()).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)

print(repr(new_a))
# array([[1, 2, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6, 6],
#        [7, 7, 8, 9]])
```